# How to remove the very large files under /hadoop/hdfs/journal/hdfsha/current/

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hdp, namenode

in our HDP cluster - version 2.6.5 , with ambari platform

we noticed that `/hadoop/hdfs/journal/hdfsha/current/`
folder include huge files and more then 1000 files as

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 hdfs hadoop 494690334 Dec 28 11:37 edits_0000000017251672645-0000000017253719335
-rw-r--r--. 1 hdfs hadoop 524892007 Dec 28 12:37 edits_0000000017253719336-0000000017255810613
-rw-r--r--. 1 hdfs hadoop 509365350 Dec 28 14:17 edits_0000000017255810614-0000000017258005682
-rw-r--r--. 1 hdfs hadoop 526756290 Dec 28 15:07 edits_0000000017258005683-0000000017260117992
```

in order to minimize the journal edit logs we can maybe use the following as part of HDFS ( hdfs-site.xml )

we not sure if the meaning of - `dfs.namenode.num.extra.edits.retained` is to retained only 100 files

please advice if the following configuration can help to purge the extra journal files in

```
dfs.namenode.num.extra.edits.retained=100
dfs.namenode.max.extra.edits.segments.retained=1
dfs.namenode.num.checkpoints.retained=1
```

reference - https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-remove-very-large-files-under-hadoophdfsnamecurrent-biginsights-30-save-disk-space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clear out the space consumed by jornal edit, you are on right track. However the values are too less and if something goes wrong, you might loose data.

The default value for `dfs.namenode.num.extra.edits.retained` and `dfs.namenode.max.extra.edits.segments.retained` is set to `1000000` and `10000` respectively.

I would suggest following values:-

```
dfs.namenode.num.extra.edits.retained=100000
dfs.namenode.max.extra.edits.segments.retained=100
dfs.namenode.num.checkpoints.retained=2
```

You can find all these parameter details [here](https://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/hadoop/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml), The values can be anything and depends on your environment you have to choose.

Comment: 'when - dfs.namenode.num.extra.edits.retained=100000 , is it means that we stay with - 100000  files?

Comment: Yes those are files,

Comment: but why 100000 , why we need so many ? because now we have less this number

Comment: You can reduce that, those are edits, incase of hdfs service crash these will help you to attempt recover data. It's always good practice to keep these as as much as you can. But again it totally depends on your environment.

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem, edits start accumulating in the NN and journal nodes. It turned out that the standBy NN is dead. reading the document and found that the merging and cleaning of the edits is the responsibility of the standBy NN.
in the non-HA mode it's the SecondaryNN that's doing this.
so make sure your standBy/Secondary NN is running correctly.